# How should I assign the fractional part to a BigDecimal that comes from a tFileInputPositional in Talend?

Tags: java, types, casting, bigdecimal, talend

I'm working with Talend Open Studio for Data Integration.

I've got a tFileInputPositional which creates several fields. One of them would look like this: "+0000030139808303".

I need to save those fields into a BigDecimal(20,2) so that the last two digits would be the fractional part but, when typing it in the component's schema, it simply adds ",00" at the end of the number.

So, summing up...
What I have:
+0000030139808303

What I want:
301398083,03

What I get:
30139808303,00

Could anyone help me to make it work?
Thanks!

Comment: You say "what I get" which suggests that you've got some current code - please show what that code is...

Comment: @JonSkeet Well, I have set up the components. Basically there is this tInputFilePositional connected to a tMap whose main output is tMysqlOutput.

Comment: @JonSkeet
When I say "What I get" I mean that those are the values that end up in my MySQL database.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "connected to a tMap"  - is this a Talend concept? (The solution probably isn't Talend-specific, and the less Talend-specific you can make the question, the better...)

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, I'm sorry for that. tMap, tInputFilePositional and tMysqlOutput are talend components, which are linked. I won't post the code itself because it's auto-generated and can't be modified, so you know how ugly those things look.
But the point is that in the tMap is where I can interact with the values (the tInputFilePositional just provides me with a schema that I can fill with the values, not entering java code).
In the tMap I can enter the part behind the "=" in a variable declaration. And that's where I've writen "row16.ObliRecNetasGtos.movePointLeft(2)".

Answer (score 1):

what about using 
`BigDecimal.movePointLeft(2)` ?

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/math/bigdecimal_movepointleft.htm

Comment: Thanks & Sorry, @MrOerni, I haven't seen your answer until just now. I've already tried it and got good results in the database, but the java console prints "null" for (I guess) every row that processes. I got the same result before, when I tried dividing. The rest of the program works well, so I guess the problem must be in there.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you just want [`BigDecimal.movePointLeft`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#movePointLeft-int-).

> Returns a BigDecimal which is equivalent to this one with the decimal point moved `n` places to the left. If `n` is non-negative, the call merely adds `n` to the scale. If `n` is negative, the call is equivalent to `movePointRight(-n)`. The `BigDecimal` returned by this call has value `(this × 10^-n)` and scale `max(this.scale()+n, 0)`.

For example:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String text = "+0000030139808303";
        BigDecimal original = new BigDecimal(text);
        BigDecimal shifted = original.movePointLeft(2);
        System.out.println(shifted);
    }    
}
```

Output:

```
301398083.03
```

Comment: Sounds good, I'll try it and let you know if it worked!
Thank you!

Comment: well, it does work. I'm getting the right values in the database. But, for some reason, the java console is printing "null" for (I guess) every row that processes. Any idea of why that happens?

Comment: @PabloIT: Not knowing anything about what is printing to the Java console, or really anything about what you're running, no...

Comment: Well, the rest of the program did work perfectly until I entered this line (only that the values weren't the right ones), so I guess that the mistake should be there. Prior to posting, I tried dividing and I got the same result. The java console only prints, apart from the connected/disconnected lines, a bunch of nulls.

Comment: It prints this:

Starting job Gastos_de_Funcionamiento_Cuentas_Formuladas_aux at 11:27 19/05/2015.
[statistics] connecting to socket on port 4031
[statistics] connected
null
null
null
null
//...
[statistics] disconnected
Job Gastos_de_Funcionamiento_Cuentas_Formuladas_aux ended at 11:27 19/05/2015. [exit code=0]

Comment: @PabloIT: Sure, but with no idea what Talend does, it's probably something Talend-specific. Put it this way: I'd be *astonished* if the call to `BigDecimal.movePointLeft` itself was printing that out. I suspect you should change this question to be just about `BigDecimal`, and then ask a new question which is *just* about Talend and spurious console output.

Comment: Ok, thank you @JonSkeet.
One last thing about your solution. Is it ok if the input and the output BigDecimals are the same length/scale? I'm asking because in your first quote it said that "n" was added to the scale. It does work with both being "20,2" but I don't want to accumulate mistakes. Thanks!